# bootstrap popover for Dynamically created buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am struck here in jquery. I have a json. I create buttons based on the number of items in the json. Popover is not getting displayed for hover action on those buttons. PLease help. I dont know where i am making the mistake. And dont have any idea in debugging. Suggestions please...

```
<style type="text/css">
    @IMPORT url("bootstrap.css");
</style>

<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/3s/Sample/JsonCreation.php', function(data)
    {   
        questionsArray = data;
        variable = 1;
        for (var question in questionsArray)
        {
            var button = $("<input>").attr("type", "button").attr("id", "buttonWithQNo").attr("class", "btn btn-default").attr("data-title", "title").attr("data-content", "content").val(variable);
            $('#questionButtonsDiv').append(button);
            $('#questionButtonsDiv').append(" ");
            variable++;
        }

    }); 
    $('#buttonWithQNo').popover({trigger: 'hover'});    
});
```

EDIT - 
I understand that the hover action is added even before the elements are added to the document model. But where should i add the hover action? And PS i need it for all the buttons(title and content on every popover is unique - its values should be derived from the json)...

Comment: every button has the same ID

Comment: I have it for my convenience. Does it have anything to do with the issue mentioned?

Comment: yes, on every page ID has to be unique for element, use css class instead as in @Subash Selvaraj answer

Comment: And u sure that u have jQuery included? Is it in bootstrap.js?

Comment: that worked. But y is it so? please explain... i use $(document).on('click', '#buttonWithQNo', function()). this works for all buttons...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/3s/Sample/JsonCreation.php', function(data)
    {   
        questionsArray = data;
        variable = 1;
        for (var question in questionsArray)
        {
            var button = $("<input>").attr("type", "button").attr("class", "btn btn-default buttonWithQNo").attr("data-title", "title").attr("data-content", "content").val(variable);
            $('#questionButtonsDiv').append(button);
            $('#questionButtonsDiv').append(" ");
            variable++;

            //
            $(button).popover({trigger: 'hover'}); 
        }


    });    
});
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/Cntj8/)

Comment: Thanks that worked a bit... But where should i add the hover action? cos the elements are added to the document model inside the getjson method... And it is not working if hover action is there in the current place..

Comment: try using the button instance inside the for loop as in my edited code. Hope it helps..